# VScrollBar.LargeChange when set not allowing any scrolling

Tags: c#

I am having trouble correctly setting the a VScrollBar.

I have a number of sub-panels on a form, and logic tells me to set SmallChange to the height of one, and the LargeChange to the combined height of as many that the user can currently see.

But the thumb tab remains maximised and scrolling is not permitted until the form is resized (where the LargeChange is reset to match the new form height). Once resized, all works as expected.

Can anyone shine some light onto this behaviour, and what I should do to fix this problem.

EDIT:

There seems to be a misunderstanding of the problem. The code works and works well, but only AFTER the form has been resized. As the same code is called upon initialisation as per the resize event, I am perplexed at what is locking the scrollbar when form first opens. The code can be cut/paste onto any form to demonstrate.

EDIT 2:

I got it working, but once again, I would like to know why...

In the bottom of the constructor where I call:

```
ResetScrollbar();
```

I now call it 3 times in a row (twice did not work).

```
ResetScrollbar();
ResetScrollbar();
ResetScrollbar();
```

This is not that satisfactory as it somewhat intelligent. But this might be able to help someone to explain the problem to me. I do not think of this hack as solving the problem.

CODE:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace VScrollBarTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private const int SubPanelHeight = 50;
        private const int SubPanelCount = 10;
        private Panel mainPanel;
        private VScrollBar mainScrollBar;
        private Panel scrollPanel;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Height = 400;

            mainPanel = new Panel()
            {
                Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
                Parent = this,
            };

            mainScrollBar = new VScrollBar()
            {
                Minimum = 0,
                Value = 0,
                SmallChange = SubPanelHeight,
                Parent = mainPanel,
                Dock = DockStyle.Right,
            };

            scrollPanel = new Panel()
            {
                Left = 0,
                Top = 0,
                Width = mainPanel.Width - SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth,
                Height = SubPanelCount * SubPanelHeight,
                Parent = mainPanel,
            };

            for (int i = 0; i < SubPanelCount; i++)
            {
                Panel p = new Panel()
                {
                    Parent = scrollPanel,
                    Left = 0,
                    Top = i * SubPanelHeight,
                    Width = scrollPanel.Width,
                    Height = SubPanelHeight,
                    Text = "Sub Panel " + (i + 1).ToString(),
                    BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle,
                    BackColor = Color.White,
                    Tag = i,
                };

                Label l = new Label()
                {
                    Parent = p,
                    Text = "Panel " + (i + 1).ToString(),
                    Left = 10,
                    TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft,
                };

                l.Top = (SubPanelHeight - l.Height) / 2;
            }

            Resize += Form3_Resize;
            mainScrollBar.Scroll += mainScrollBar_Scroll;

            ResetScrollbar();
        }

        private void Form3_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ResetScrollbar();
        }

        private void mainScrollBar_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
        {
            scrollPanel.Top = -e.NewValue;
        }

        private void ResetScrollbar()
        {
            mainScrollBar.LargeChange = ((int)(mainPanel.Height / SubPanelHeight)) * SubPanelHeight;
            mainScrollBar.Maximum = SubPanelCount * SubPanelHeight - (scrollPanel.Height < mainPanel.Height ? scrollPanel.Height : mainPanel.Height) + mainScrollBar.LargeChange - 1;
        }
     }

}
```

Comment: Thankyou, but still having problems. The scroll bar works inasmuch that I can now scroll to 8 of the subpanels, but I still have to resize to see the rest.

Comment: The scrollbar sits on the mainPanel and controls the scrollPanel. The subPanels are locked onto the scrollPanel, but give an indication of movement.

Comment: There seems to be a misunderstanding of the problem. The code works and works well, but only AFTER the form has been resized. As the same code is called upon initialisation as per the resize event, I am perplexed at what is locking the scrollbar when form first opens. The code can be cut/paste onto any form to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a new *scrollBar* the default value of *Maximum is 100*. The part:

```
mainScrollBar.LargeChange = ((int)(mainPanel.Height / SubPanelHeight)) * SubPanelHeight;
```

gives *mainScrollBar.LargeChange = 350* which is larger than *Maximum* (it cant be) so it sets it automatically to 101. Then you calculate the *Maximum(mainScrollBar.LargeChange = 101)*:

```
mainScrollBar.Maximum = SubPanelCount * SubPa........ = 238
```

which again is smaller than 350 and finally sets *mainScrollBar.LargeChange = 239*.

You need to calculate **first** the *Maximum* and then the *LargeChange*:

```
mainScrollBar.Maximum = SubPanelCount * SubPanelHeight - 1;
mainScrollBar.LargeChange = mainPanel.Height;
```

Comment: Thankyou γηράσκω δ' αεί πολλά διδασκόμε for your answer and explanation. It worked! My hat off to you.

Comment: Just playing around with the statements, and it does not seem to matter what order they go. But I think I now see where I was going wrong. I was taking into consideration the height of the mainPanel when working out the scrollbar maximum (you only need to scroll the difference of what you cannot see against that which you can), but it would appear the scrollbar does this automatically with the value in LargeChange. Now it makes sense why all other posts deduct LargeChage when calculating the Maximum. Thankyou again good sir for your help.